# Apply css to input tag in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have in my react js application the next component:

```
const Input = ({name, ..rest}) => {
  return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name={name} {...rest}/>
        {errors && <span>Error: Please add your name</span>}
      </div>
  );
};
```

The `rest` parameter contains all `React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>` like required, className, id, etc ....
 I encountered an issue trying to add `style` prop to the Input component. In this way if i will add like:

`margin-bottom: 45px`

then between input and the span will appear the space, but the space should be intended for the entire component, so the margin should be applied below the component not between the elements from the component.

How to avoid the issue keeping the `...rest` on input tag?

Note: Apart from `style`, there could be used in the same context and `className`, `id`, `required` and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your problem, but why don't you put the `margin` to the `div`, not to the `span`?

Comment: yes its not clear tbh what it is currently happening and the expected result ... can you add some reproducible sample explaining the same

Answer (score 0):

You could pull out the `style` prop from the `rest`, then remove it's `margin` prop (that was set before) and overwrite it with your custom margin - `marginBottom: 45`.

```
const Input = ({ name, style, ...rest }) => {
  const { margin, ...restStyles } = style;
  const newStyles = {
    ...restStyles,
    marginBottom: 45,
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name={name} {...rest} style={newStyles} />
                                               // ^^^^^^^^^ applying new styles
        {errors && <span>Error: Please add your name</span>}
      </div>
  );
};
```